# Does cron ignore *-bak files?

Tags: cron

After an upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 I saw that the file /etc/cron.d/mdadm.dpkg-bak was left in place. I wonder if -bak files are actually ignored by anacron or where is the documentation regarding this?
I just want to make sure it does not run twice once started by systemd and once started by cron (because I have had some weird raid scrubbing related issues).
Thanks

Comment: It uses `run-parts`, and `run-parts` doesn't like `.` in the filename. So it will ignore `*.dpkg-bak`

Comment: Great to know thanks!